# Basis for nullspace of stochastic matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, markov-chains

Given a stochastic matrix $P$ representing a Markov chain, I am supposed to find the basis of:
$$
\operatorname{Null}(P-I_5)
$$

What is this expression supposed to represent and how do I proceed to solve it?

How is this related to the regularity of matrix $P$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the Perron-Frobenius theorem and the regularity of $P$, $P^k$ has exactly one eigenvalue of magnitude $1$ for some $k$, and the geometric multiplicity of this eigenvalue is $1$.

We may deduce that the same must also hold for $P$.